# Sending and Receiving data from a website to NodeJs application

Tags: node.js, web, connection, bots, discord

basically I am trying to figure out a way to make a connection between my Discord Bot and my Website, I have some ideas in mind in using GET and POST methods but IDK how to use them in NodeJs nor in the website as I am still new to it, so what I want is to send a packet of data from the website after a submit button and the bot which is hosted locally with the website will receive this data and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Express is a commonly used web framework for Node that takes care of routing fairly easily. You can see their documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).